# Schema for a Soccer club

Tags: database-design

I am designing a database for a Soccer club. A soccer club has several teams. Those teams have several players and a coach.

Right now I have three tables:

```
Club
Team (foreign key to club)
Player (foreign key to team)
```

My main concern is that, each season a Team brings in new players and therefore, I need somehow to state that. I want to be able to maintain a record of the Team along the different seasons, and also be able to know what a Team is in the current season. How could I model that?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add another table Season, and another table SeasonPlayer with an FK to player, an FK to team and an FK to Season.

Then drop the FK from Team to Player in your current schema